# Java Swing GUI updating/changing from method - freezing in loop

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

basically, I have this code which was initially working with console i/o now I have to connect it to **UI**. It may be completely wrong, I've tried multiple things although it still ends up with freezing the GUI.

I've tried to redirect console I/O to GUI scrollpane, but the GUI freezes anyway. Probably it has to do something with threads, but I have limited knowledge on it so I need the deeper explanation how to implement it in this current situation.

> **This is the button on GUI class containing the method that needs to change this GUI.**

```
public class GUI {
 ...
btnNext.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                controller.startTest(index, idUser);

        }
    });
 }
```

> **This is the method startTest from another class which contains instance of Question class.**

```
public int startTest()  {

    for (int i = 0; i < this.numberofQuestions; i++) {
        Question qt = this.q[i];
            qt.askQuestion(); <--- This needs to change Label in GUI

        if(!qt.userAnswer())  <--- This needs to get string from TextField
            decreaseScore(1);    

    }

   return actScore();

}
```

> **askQuestion method:**

```
   public void askQuestion() {
    System.out.println(getQuestion());
    /* I've tried to change staticaly declared frame in GUI from there */


}
```

> **userAnswer method:**

```
 public boolean userAnswer() {
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    if( Objects.equals(getAnswer(),userInput) ) {
        System.out.println("Correct");
        return true;
    }

    System.out.println("False");            
    return false;

}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: You need to read abot [concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html). Basically you should not performe any long-time operation in your event handlers. All long-time operations should be implented using the `SwingWorker` class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct in thinking that it related to threads.

When you try executing code that will take a long time to process (eg. downloading a large file) in the swing thread, the swing thread will pause to complete execution and cause the GUI to freeze. This is solved by executing the long running code in a separate thread.

As [Sergiy Medvynskyy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1989769/sergiy-medvynskyy) pointed out in his comment, you need to implement the long running code in the [SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) class.

A good way to implement it would be this:

```
public class TestWorker extends SwingWorker<Integer, String> {

  @Override
  protected Integer doInBackground() throws Exception {
    //This is where you execute the long running
    //code
    controller.startTest(index, idUser);
    publish("Finish");
  }

  @Override
  protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
    //Called when the task has finished executing.
    //This is where you can update your GUI when
    //the task is complete or when you want to
    //notify the user of a change.
  }
}
```

Use `TestWorker.execute()` to start the worker.

[This](http://www.javacreed.com/swing-worker-example/) website provides a good example on how to use
the SwingWorker class.

Answer (score -1):

As other answers pointed out, doing heavy work on the GUI thread will freeze the GUI. You can use a `SwingWorker` for that, but in many cases a simple `Thread` does the job:

```
Thread t = new Thread(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        // do stuff
    }
};
t.start();
```

Or if you use Java 8+:

```
Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
    // do stuff
});
t.start();
```

Comment: (1-)  You don't want to us a Thread because all Swing components should be updated on the Event Dispatch Thread. A SwingWorker has methods that do this for you. Read the tutorial that was provided as a comment to this question.

Comment: I know, but a SwingWorker adds a lot of boilerplate code that can be avoided for smaller tasks